# Print Specific Columns using AWK

Tags: awk

I'm trying to fetch the data from column B to D from a tab delimited file "FILE". The simple AWK code I use fetch the data, but unfortunately keeps the output in a single column and remove the identifiers (shown below).

Any suggestions please.

CODE

```
 awk '{for(i=2;i<=4;++i)print $i}' FILE
```

FILE

```
           A            B               C               D               E               F             G
   1_at   10.8435630935 10.8559287854   8.6666141543    8.820310681     9.9024050571    8.613199083   11.9807771094
   2_at   4.7615531106  4.5209119307    11.2467919586   8.8105151099    7.1831990104    11.0645055836 4.3726598561
   3_at   6.0025262754  5.4058080843    3.2475272982    3.1869728585    3.5654989547
```

OUTPUT OBTAINED

```
B
C
D
10.8435630935
10.8559287854
8.6666141543
4.7615531106
4.5209119307
11.2467919586
6.0025262754
5.4058080843
3.2475272982
```

Comment: `awk '{print $3,$4,$5}'` ?

Comment: `awk '$0=$2" "$3" "$4'` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you directly use `cut`?

```
$ cut -d$'\t' -f2-4 < file
B C D
10.8435630935 10.8559287854 8.6666141543
4.7615531106 4.5209119307 11.2467919586
6.0025262754 5.4058080843 3.2475272982
```

With `awk` you would need `printf` to avoid new lines of `print`:

```
awk -F"\t" '{for(i=2;i<=4;++i) printf "%s%s", $i, (i==4?RS:FS)}'
```

Comment: Why would you iterate through though ?

Comment: I added it to show how it should be done, although certainly there is no need.